# How to join tables with multiple branches in JPA NamedQuery

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb, eclipselink

I am developing a web application in `JavaEE` where i am using `JPA` **Named Queries** to query against the database. However, i don't know how to do that when having to join tables with multiple branches, and i tried to build and execute some queries for the following situation but it all always returns `null`.

Here is an image that describes my situation:
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKj1b.png)

where i am trying to select field from multiple tables(Entities) with multiple JOIN using `@NamedQuery`.Please note that i removed setters and `getters` from the below classes to reduce code size.

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners({Logger.class})
public abstract class SuperEntity  implements Serializable,HasName{

    @Transient
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6420076371961889265L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(initialValue = 0, allocationSize = 1, name = "IdGenerator")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "IdGenerator")
    private long ID;

    @Version
    private long version;
}




            @Entity
            public class Party extends SuperEntity {

                @Length(min = 1, max = 30, message = "Invalid party name.")
                private String name;

                @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
                @NotNull
                private PartyType type;

                @Length(min = 1, max = 13, message = "Invalid phone number")
                private String phone;

                @Email(message = "Invalid email address.")
                @NotNull
                private String email;

                @NotNull
                @NotEmpty(message = "Party address is required.")
                private String address;

                @Valid
                @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "party", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
                private List<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();

        }

                @Entity
            public class Vehicle extends SuperEntity {

                @Valid
                @Embedded
                private VehicleAttributes attributes;

                @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE})
                @JoinColumn(name = "partyID")
                private Party party;

                @Valid
                @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "vehicle",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
                private List<FixRequest> fixRequests = new ArrayList<FixRequest>();
           } 


            @NamedQuery(name = FixRequest.GET_NOT_PAID_REQUESTS_BY_PARTY_QUERY, query = "Select new org.master.jpa.UnpaidFixRequestObject(v.attributes.type,v.attributes.model,fr.ID,fr.requestDate,SUM(f.cost),SUM(p.paidAmount)) From Vehicle v,FixRequest fr,Payment p,Fix f,FixJoin fj WHERE v=fr.vehicle AND fr=p.fixRequest AND fr=fj.fixRequest AND fj.fix=f AND v.party.ID=:partyID GROUP BY v.attributes.type,v.attributes.model,fr.ID,fr.requestDate")
            @Entity
            public class FixRequest extends SuperEntity implements Serializable {

            @Transient
            static final String GET_NOT_PAID_REQUESTS_BY_PARTY_QUERY = "getNotPaidRequestsByParty";
            @Transient
            static final String GET_NOT_PAID_REQUESTS_BY_PARTY_QUERY_PARTY_PARAM = "partyID";
                @NotNull
                @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
                private Date requestDate;

                @NotNull
                @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
                private Date requestedFixDate;

                @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE})
                @JoinColumn(name = "vehicleID")
                private Vehicle vehicle;

                @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy="fixRequest")
                private List<TroubleJoin> request_Troubles = new ArrayList<TroubleJoin>();

                @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy="fixRequest")
                private List<FixJoin> requset_Fixes = new ArrayList<FixJoin>();

                @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy="fixRequest")
                private List<Payment> payments = new ArrayList<Payment>();

                private String details;
        }

        @Entity
        public class FixJoin extends SuperEntity implements Serializable {

            public FixJoin() {
                super();
            }

            @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE})
            @JoinColumn(name = "fixRequestID")
            private FixRequest fixRequest;

            @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE})
            @JoinColumn(name = "fixID")
            private Fix fix;

            private String details;
        }

        @Entity
        public class Fix extends SuperEntity implements Serializable {

            @NotEmpty
            @NotNull
            private String type;

            @NotEmpty
            @NotNull
            private String detail;

            @Column(precision = 2)
            @Min(value = 1)
            private double cost;

            @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE},fetch=FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="fix")
            private List<FixJoin> requset_Fixes = new ArrayList<FixJoin>();
        }

        @Entity
        public class Payment extends SuperEntity implements Serializable {

            @Transient
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Column(precision = 2)
            private double paidAmount;

            @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
            private PaymentMethod paymentMethod;

            private int checkNumber;

            private String bank;

            private String payer;

            private String reciever;

            private String notes;

            @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE})
            @JoinColumn(name = "fixRequestId")
            private FixRequest fixRequest;
        }

        @Stateless
        public class QueryFacade {

            @PersistenceContext
            EntityManager entityManager;


        public List<UnpaidFixRequestObject> getUnpaidFixRequestObjects(long partyID){
            TypedQuery<UnpaidFixRequestObject> typedQuery = entityManager.createNamedQuery(FixRequest.getGetNotPaidRequestsByPartyQuery(),UnpaidFixRequestObject.class);
            typedQuery.setParameter(FixRequest.getGetNotPaidRequestsByPartyQueryPartyParam(), partyID);
            return typedQuery.getResultList();
        }
        }

        @ViewScoped
        @ManagedBean
        public class PaymentFace {

            @EJB
            private FootprintEntityFacade<Payment> paymentFacade;

            @EJB
            QueryFacade queryFacade;

            private List<Party> parties;
            private List<UnpaidFixRequestObject> unpaidFixRequests;

            private String selectedParty = "";
            private String selectedFixRequest = "";
            private Payment payment;

            private boolean showCreditPaymentControls = false;

            @PostConstruct
            public void init() {
                parties = new ArrayList<Party>();
                unpaidFixRequests = new ArrayList<UnpaidFixRequestObject>();

                parties = queryFacade.getAllParties();
                for (Party p : parties) {
                    p.setName(p.getID() + " - " + p.getName() + " - " + p.getAddress());
                }
            unpaidFixRequests = queryFacade.getUnpaidFixRequestObjects(parties.get(0).getID());
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Place your query, lets see what going on there

Comment: Thanks for your reply, below is my most recent query i tried where it returns null:          Select new org.master.jpa.UnpaidFixRequestObject(v.attributes.type,v.attributes.model,fr.ID,fr.requestDate,SUM(f.cost),SUM(p.paidAmount)) From Vehicle v,FixRequest fr,Payment p,Fix f,FixJoin fj WHERE v=fr.vehicle AND fr=p.fixRequest AND fr=fj.fixRequest AND fj.fix=f AND v.party.ID=:partyID GROUP BY v.attributes.type,v.attributes.model,fr.ID,fr.requestDate

Comment: Plase place that in the post with proper editing and also.. as the tables are simple, add your entity mapping. Lets see the whole picture

Comment: sorry for that, the above image only describes the situation, just a minuet and i will edit my post

Comment: i edited my post please check..and thanks alot.

Comment: i added my the JSF and EJB implementation also

Answer (score 0):

Ok try this query, i have added explicit joins:

```
"Select new org.master.jpa.UnpaidFixRequestObject(v.attributes.type,v.at‌​tributes.model,fr.ID‌​,fr.requestDate,SUM(‌​f.cost),SUM(p.paidAm‌​ount)) " +
            " From FixRequest fr" +
            "   inner join fr.payments p" +
            "   inner join fr.vehicle v" +
            "   inner join v.party pt" +
            "   inner join fr.requset_Fixes rf" +
            "   inner join rf.fix f"
            " WHERE pt.ID=:partyID " +
            " GROUP BY v.attributes.type,v.attributes.model,fr.ID,fr.requestDate"
```

Comment: sorry but id didn't work cuz it seems that you cannot add table(entity) alias after JOIN, please check the image here [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kp1tzqi6oyv44rl/Untitled1.png?dl=0) @Maciej Kowalski

Comment: this small typo fixes some of the errors but there are still there some marked with red, almost done please check the image here [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wsodno8xb4yzdo2/Untitled2.png?dl=0) @Maciej Kowalski

Comment: Run the query, lets see what happens at runtime. Those syntax checking tools are sometimes faulty.

Comment: i tried to restart the application server and the IDE also and the syntax is still unaccepted by the compiler. also i tried to run my application but the application server crashes saying : **org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException The identification variable '‌?f' is not following the rules for a Java identifier**. @Maciej Kowalski

Comment: add the SuperEntity class to post

Comment: i did it please checkup @Maciej Kowalski

Comment: There is not '?f' string in my query. Are you sure this comes from invoking this query?

Comment: The error is caused by the SuperEntity , jpql does not work wth MappedSuperclass

Answer (score 0):

Write the query of **@Maciej** And change your model by moving the ID from the SuperEntity  to all the others classes.

> The default access type of an entity hierarchy is determined by the placement of mapping annotations on the attributes of the entity classes and mapped superclasses of the entity hierarchy that do not explicitly specify an access type.

Read more : [Multiple @MappedSuperclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226392/multiple-mappedsuperclass)